# Как передать аргумент в std::thread по ссылке?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Как передать аргумент функции в `std::thread` по ссылке? Хоть моя функция принимает параметр по ссылке, но похоже, что объекты всё равно разные.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все аргументы, передаваемые при запуске `std::thread`, будут копироваться и сама функция потока получит ссылки на копии. Поэтому, разумеется, объекты будут разные.

Чтобы произошла передача по ссылке в `std::thread` вместо `arg` следует передавать `std::ref(arg)` или `std::cref(arg)`.

Comment: Спасибо, работает теперь. А почему так сделано?

Comment: @zorg: Так как поток после запуска начнет жить своей самостоятельной жизнью, никак не синхронизированной с пределами времени жизни объектов в запускающем коде, вполне естественно, что поток хочет брать все свои параметры "с собой", т.е. копирует все параметры "к себе". А если вы все таки хотите "рискнуть" и взять на себя ответственность за корректное поддержание времени жизни внешних объектов, то у вас есть такая возможность: передавайте голые указатели или `std::ref`.