# Как передать в поток указатель на переменную с++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

есть функция

```
void t(int aa) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){            
       if(aa==0){
           std::cout<<"Поток номер = "<<std::this_thread::get_id()
                    <<"   Отработал итерацию - "<<i<<std::endl;
           sleep(1);
        }
        else{
            aa--;
            std::cout<<"поток "<<std::this_thread::get_id()
                      <<"   уснул - "<<std::endl;
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
}
```

суть этой функции в том что потоки спокойно делают свои итерации (допустим потоков штук 10) но в один момент функция t() которую выполняют потоки,видит переменную аа которая лежит в главном потоке функции main() . И допустим аа = 2
Это значит что 2 потока должны заснуть,любые из 10. те кто первые увидят  аа делают ее аа--; и засыпают на 5 секунд .

Вопрос вот в чем , как сделать переменную аа видимой для всех потоков и изменяемой для всех потоков?

Comment: Что такое `aa`?

Comment: Вообще это часть вопроса ,чем должно быть аа)  Но по сути это что то вроде переменной типа int которая хранит значение кол-ва потоков которые нужно усыпить

Answer (score 1):

Просто передавайте аа по ссылке или указателю, а при использовании захватывайте мьютекс

Comment: а как это будет выглядеть если передавать параметр в поток?

Comment: Ранее я делал это так, но сработает ли такое если функция test  получает на вход ссылку а потоку надо передавать вроде как указатель  
 threads.push_back(std::thread(test,аа));

Comment: @ИгорьБутков как правильно передать аргумент по ссылке смотрите в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/920143/317064) ответе