# Как передать в поток параметром ссылку

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

я создаю некоторое количество потоков и делаю это вот так.

```
  for(int i=0; i<minThread;i++){
        threads.push_back(std::thread(test,sosTest));
        std::cout<<"Поток "<<i<<" создан"<<std::endl;
    }


    std::for_each(threads.begin(),threads.end(),std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
```

вопрос такой. Как мне передать в поток параметр для функции test() если этот параметр ссылка а не указатель?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [`ref()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

Comment: Можно получить указатель на ссылку - и на другой стороне пользоваться им через ссылку. Так же на той стороне сделать из указателя ссылку можно (чуть сложнее). Язык с++ позволяет это сделать.

Comment: Недавно же было. Смотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/920143/317064) ответ

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи параметра по ссылке в процедуру потока достаточно обвернуть его в `std::ref`.

Ваш код будет выглядеть как (если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите обвернуть sosTest) :

```
 threads.push_back(std::thread(test,std::ref(sosTest)));
```